# Как сделать так, чтобы короткие слова(предлоги, местоимения и т.д.) переносились на новую строку автоматически?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот пример текста:

> Человек, который никогда **не** делал ошибок, никогда **не** пробовал ничего нового.<

В зависимости от разрешения экрана устройства, у всех разное количество символов отображается на экране(спасибо КЭП). Как сделать так, чтобы '**не**' всегда переносилось на новую строку, если остается последним словом в строке?

Comment: Последний вопрос немного не понятный. "чтобы 'не' всегда переносилось, когда остается последним словом в строке". Какой строке? Во время отображения в каком-то блоке?

Comment: Например, есть такой текст. Чтобы при чтении с телефонов, короткие символы не закрывали строку, а переносились на новую.  
`<p> 
Согласно самой распространённой легенде, братья Ромул и Рем, рождённые от дочери царя Альба-Лонги, Реи Сильвии и бога Марса, выросли на берегу Тибра. Восстановив на троне Альба-Лонги законного правителя — своего деда Нумитора, Ромул и Рем вернулись к Тибру для основания колонии. Между братьями возникла ссора: Ромул убил Рема и основал укреплённое поселение на Палатине. 
</p>`

Comment: Можно типографом подготовить: https://www.artlebedev.ru/typograf/

Comment: Текст корпоративный, поэтому такой вариант не подходит)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1: в тексте после предлогов вместо обычного пробела вставлять неразрывный (`&nbsp;`) - он предназначен именно для таких случаев.

Вариант 2: слова вместе с предшествующими предлогами оборачивать в элемент с CSS-свойствами `display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap;`

Первый вариант на порядки кошернее.

Если текст содержимого не ваш, а вы его получаете откуда-то, то тут без скрипта не обойтись. Примерно так: пройти по всему тексту и заменить слова_из_не_более_двух_(трех/сколько_надо)_букв + все_пробелы_и_разрывы_строк_подряд на эти же слова плюс неразрывный пробел.